# Jquery How to trigger buttons upon radio select

Tags: jquery, html, checkbox

After validate I need to trigger custom submits on different hidden buttons. Code works fine but it do only default. What I`m doing wrong?

Here is spart off form:

```
<label for="a1"><input id="a1" type="radio" name="method" value="PayPal" validate="required:true" checked>PayPal</label>
<label for="a2"><input id="a2" type="radio" name="method" value="SEB">SEB</label>
```

...

```
<input class="checkout" type="button" value="checkout">
<input class="paypal" type="button" value="paypal">
```

Nad here is script
...

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#checkout").validate({
        success: "valid",
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var v = "$('input[name=method]:checked', '#checkout').val()";
            switch(v){
                case "PayPal": $('.paypal').trigger('click');
                default: ^$('.checkout').trigger('click');
                break;
            }         
        }
    });
});
```

I need any fresh ideas to make this work.

Comment: you might want to delete the "^" on default: ^$('.checkout').trigger('click');

Comment: add break just before default

Comment: ^ is special char for compatibility so it`s ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, you haven't broke on your case:

Also, you have extra quotes around your `var v` declaration

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#checkout").validate({
        success: "valid",
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var v = $('input[name=method]:checked', '#checkout').val();
            switch(v){
                case "PayPal": $('.paypal').trigger('click');
                break;
                default: $('.checkout').trigger('click');
                break;
            }         
        }
    });
});
```